# How to extract the filename extension out of %f in script?

Tags: windows, script, console, filenames, file-extension

The windows %%f returns the full name of the file as 'filename.ext'

e.g.

```
for /r %%f in (*.wav) do echo %%f
```

Is there a way to extract the filename **without the extension** from %%f?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change echo %%f to echo %%~nf.

~n tells the cmd to expand f to equal only the filename, minus the extension.

Comment: Thanks mate!
May I be so bold as to enquire how you acquired that little tid-bit?

Comment: From the horse's mouth: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490909.aspx. Generally, anything Product related is going to be under technet.microsoft.com.  Anything programming related is going to be under msdn.microsoft.com (Microsoft Developer's network).